# Rust: Read dataframe in polars from mysql

Tags: mysql, dataframe, rust, rust-sqlx, rust-polars

##### Problem

How to read a dataframe in polars from mysql.
[Docs](https://docs.rs/polars/0.15.1/polars/index.html) are silent on the issue. Currently probably there is only support for parquet, json, ipc, etc, and no direct support for `sql` as mentioned [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/index.html#compile-times-and-opt-in-features).

Regardless what would be an appropriate method to read in data using libraries like: [`sqlx`](https://lib.rs/crates/sqlx) or [`mysql`](https://lib.rs/crates/mysql)

##### Current Approach

Currently I am following this approach as provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112232/how-to-create-a-dataframe-in-polars-using-a-vector-of-structs-veccountry):

1. Read in a `Vec<Struct>` using `sqlx`
2. Convert it into a tuple of vecs `(Vec<T>, Vec<T>)` using the code below
3. Convert `(Vec<T>, Vec<T>)` into `(Series, Series)`
4. Create a dataframe using: `DataFrame::new(vec![s0, s1])`; where `s0` and `s1` are `Series`

```rust
struct A(u8, i8);

fn main() {
    let v = vec![A(1, 4), A(2, 6), A(3, 5)];

    let result = v.into_iter()
        .fold((vec![], vec![]), |(mut u, mut i), item| {
            u.push(item.0);
            i.push(item.1);
            (u, i)
        });
    
    dbg!(result);

    // `result` is just a tuple of vectors
    // let (unsigneds, signeds): (Vec<u8>, Vec<i8>) = result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can help you?

```
let schema = Arc::new(Schema::new(vec![
    Field::new("country", DataType::Int64, false),
    Field::new("count", DataType::Int64, false),
]));

let datas = RecordBatch::try_new(
    schema.clone(),
    vec![
        Arc::new(Int64Array::from(vec![1, 1, 2])),
        Arc::new(Int64Array::from(vec![1, 2, 3])),
    ],
)
.unwrap();

let mut df = DataFrame::try_from(datas)?;
```

Answer (score 4):

Same answer as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112232/rust-dataframe-in-polars-using-a-vector-of-structs), seems quite duplicate IMO.

You could use the builders for that or collect from iterators. Collecting from iterators is often fast, but in this case it requires you to loop the `Vec<Country>` twice, so you should benchmark.

Below is an example function for both the solutions shown.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

struct Country {
    country: String,
    count: i64,
}

fn example_1(values: &[Country]) -> (Series, Series) {
    let ca_country: Utf8Chunked = values.iter().map(|v| &*v.country).collect();
    let ca_count: NoNull<Int64Chunked> = values.iter().map(|v| v.count).collect();
    let mut s_country: Series = ca_country.into();
    let mut s_count: Series = ca_count.into_inner().into();
    s_country.rename("country");
    s_count.rename("country");
    (s_count, s_country)
}

fn example_2(values: &[Country]) -> (Series, Series) {
    let mut country_builder = Utf8ChunkedBuilder::new("country", values.len(), values.len() * 5);
    let mut count_builder = PrimitiveChunkedBuilder::<Int64Type>::new("count", values.len());

    values.iter().for_each(|v| {
        country_builder.append_value(&v.country);
        count_builder.append_value(v.count)
    });

    (
        count_builder.finish().into(),
        country_builder.finish().into(),
    )
}
```

Once you've got the `Series`, you can use `DataFrame::new(columns)` where `columns: Vec<Series>` to create a `DataFrame`.

Btw, if you want maximum performance, I really recommend [connector-x](https://crates.io/crates/connectorx). It has got polars and arrow integration and has got insane performance.