# Create a polars dataframe from postgres sql in a generic way

Tags: rust-polars

Hi I am trying to read from postgres into a polars frame in a generic way.

I have read a post here
[Rust: Read dataframe in polars from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69117734/rust-read-dataframe-in-polars-from-mysql)

about reading from mysql and want to change this so I don't need to handle the columns for each new query.

I was planning on storing all the values in a large vector ordered by columns first.
Storing each type in an enum.

I have the following code.

```rust
let rows = client.query(&select_sql, &[]).await?;

  #[derive(Clone, Debug)]
  enum GenericValue {
    String(String),
    Bool(bool),
    DateTime(DateTime<Utc>),
    Int32(i32),
    UInt(u32),
  }

  let number_of_rows = rows.len();
  let number_of_columns = rows.first().expect("expected one row").columns().len();

  println!("Number of columns: {:?}", number_of_columns);
  println!("Number of rows: {:?}", number_of_rows);

  let mut data: Vec<Option<GenericValue>> = vec![None; number_of_columns * number_of_rows]; 

  for (row_index, row) in rows.iter().enumerate() {

    for (col_index, column) in row.columns().iter().enumerate() {
        let colType: String = column.type_().to_string();
        
        let index = col_index * number_of_columns + row_index;

        if colType == "int4" { 
            data[index] = Some(GenericValue::Int32(row.get(col_index)));
        }
        else if colType == "text" {
            data[index] = Some(GenericValue::String(row.get(col_index)));
        }
        else if colType == "varchar" {
          data[index] = Some(GenericValue::String(row.get(col_index)));
        }
        else if colType == "bool" {
            data[index] = Some(GenericValue::Bool(row.get(col_index)));
        }
        else if colType == "timestamptz" {
          data[index] = Some(GenericValue::DateTime(row.get(col_index)));
        }
        else {
            panic!("{}", &colType);
        }
    }

   for c in 0 .. number_of_columns {

      let start_index = c * number_of_columns;
      let slice = data[start_index .. start_index + number_of_rows];

      let first: Option<GenericValue> = data[start_index];

      let chunked_data: Utf8Chunked = slice.iter().map(|v| v.unwrap()).collect();

      println!("{:?}", chunked_data);


      // let ca_country: Utf8Chunked = values.iter().map(|v| &*v.country).collect();

   }
```

The problem is I need to implement  the trait `PolarsAsRef<str>` for`GenericValue`
which I am not sure how to do and how would this chunked data handle NULLS ?
How can I create the correct chunked data for each series here ?

Note this is to move away from connectorx as it still seems pinned to a very old polars
and I don't get much performance benefits from it anyway as I use partitioned postgres tables which seem to break connectorx's parallelism.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I answered it like below.
Seems to be a real lack of docs and examples on this.

```
use arrow2::array::{Array, Int32Array, Utf8Array, StructArray};

use polars_core::prelude::ArrayRef;

use arrow2::datatypes::{DataType, Field, Schema};
use polars::prelude::*;

use tokio_postgres::{Client, NoTls, Error, ToStatement};
use tokio_postgres::binary_copy::BinaryCopyInWriter;
use tokio_postgres::types::ToSql;
use tokio_postgres::types::Type;
use tokio_postgres::{Row, Column};

use polars_core::chunked_array::ChunkedArray; // ::from_chunks

async fn postgres_to_polars(rows: &[Row]) -> std::result::Result<DataFrame, PolarsError> {

    let mut fields: Vec<(String, polars_core::datatypes::DataType)> = Vec::new();
    let column_count = rows[0].len();
    for i in 0..column_count {
        let field_name = rows[0].columns()[i].name().to_string();
        let data_type: polars_core::datatypes::DataType = match rows[0].columns()[i].type_() {
            &Type::VARCHAR => polars_core::datatypes::DataType::Utf8,
            &Type::INT4 => polars_core::datatypes::DataType::Int32,
            // Add more cases for other PostgreSQL types as needed
            _ => panic!("Unsupported PostgreSQL data type"),
        };
        // let field = Field::new(&field_name, data_type, false);
        fields.push((field_name, data_type));
    }

    let first_row = rows.first().unwrap();

    let mut arrow_arrays: Vec<Vec<ArrayRef>> = vec![];
    
    for (col_index, column) in first_row.columns().iter().enumerate() {

        let mut array_data: Vec<ArrayRef> = vec![];

        for (row_index, row) in rows.iter().enumerate() {
  
            let array: ArrayRef = match column.type_() {
                &Type::VARCHAR => Box::new(Utf8Array::<i64>::from(vec![Some(row.try_get::<usize, String>(col_index).unwrap())])),
                &Type::INT4 => Box::new(Int32Array::from(vec![Some(row.try_get(col_index).unwrap())])),
                // Add more cases for other PostgreSQL types as needed
                _ => panic!("Unsupported PostgreSQL data type"),
            };
  
            array_data.push(array);
  
        }

        arrow_arrays.push(array_data);
    }

    let mut series: Vec<Series> = vec![];

    for (array, field) in arrow_arrays.iter().zip(fields.iter()) {

        unsafe {

            let s = Series::from_chunks_and_dtype_unchecked(
                &field.0,
                array.to_vec(),
                &field.1
            );

            series.push(s);
        }
    }
    
    let df: PolarsResult<DataFrame> = DataFrame::new(series);

    df
}
```

Comment: Hi! 
I found this solution interesting since I have the need for something along these lines for a Data Engineering project in Rust. I was thinking though if you have done any work on other Postgres data types, e.g. Numeric or Timestamp, for example? Maybe more specifically Numeric. Would love to hear someones experience thoughts on this. Hats of for a nice solution! :)