# How to convert a RecordBatch (Arrow type) into a Polars Dataframe in Rust

Tags: rust, apache-arrow, rust-polars

I have a record batch data in the following format.

###### Defining a schema

```
let schema = Arc::new(Schema::new(vec![
    Field::new("store_id", DataType::Int64, false),
    Field::new("week_id", DataType::Int64, false),
]));
```

###### Applying a schema on vectors

```
let datas = RecordBatch::try_new(
    schema.clone(),
    vec![
        Arc::new(Int64Array::from(vec![1, 1, 2])),
        Arc::new(Int64Array::from(vec![1, 2, 3])),
    ],
)
    .unwrap();



let mut polars_df = DataFrame::try_from(datas);
```

It resulted in error that `RecordBatch` is not implemented for `Dataframe`.

How do I convert this to a polars dataframe in Rust. I tried following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69117734/rust-read-dataframe-in-polars-from-mysql) but getting error that its not been implement for polars dataframe